# How do I to show images before upload?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to show multiple images before upload to show but I cannot to do this works.

How do I to do this ?

**Jquery**

```
function readMultiImgs(e, idElement) {    
    $.each(e.files, function (i, file) {        
        var img = document.createElement("img");        
        img.id = "image" + (i + 1);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            img.src = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        //$("#image" + i).after(img);
        $('#' + idElement).append("<div class='col-md-2'>" + img + "</div>");
    });
};
```

**Html**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="imagem550x750" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="row" id="imgs550x750">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;margin-top:5px;">                                        
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <label class="btn btn-file">
                                            Escolha a imagem @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.IMGS_D550x750, new { Class = "img_load", multiple = "multiple", type = "file", @onchange = "readMultiImgs('" + "this" + "','" + "imgs550x750" + "')" }) 
                                        </label>                                            
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><!--/col1-->
                        </div><!--/row-->
                    </div><!--/tab-pane-imagem550x750-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two issues in your code. Firsty, `'this'` in the `onchange` function call should be just `this`, without quotes, as you need to send the current element reference, not a string.

Secondly, you're trying to concatenate the `img` Element object to a string to be appended in jQuery. Instead you need to create the `div` then append the `img` to it. Try this:

```js
function readMultiImgs(e, idElement) {
  $.each(e.files, function(i, file) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      img.src = reader.result;
    }
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    $('<div class="col-md-2" />').append(img).appendTo('#' + idElement);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="imagem550x750" role="tabpanel">
  <div class="row" id="imgs550x750">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;margin-top:5px;">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <label class="btn btn-file">
            Escolha a imagem             
            <input type="file" class="img_load" multiple="multiple" onchange="readMultiImgs(this, 'imgs550x750')" />
            <!-- @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.IMGS_D550x750, new { Class = "img_load", multiple = "multiple", type = "file", @onchange = "readMultiImgs('" + "this" + "','" + "imgs550x750" + "')" }) -->
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you can avoid the need for the `onchange` attribute in your HTML (and therefore the use of `this`) by using unobtrusive event handlers. This method is considered better practice as it keeps your JS and HTML separate.

```js
$('.img_load').on('change', e => {
  Array.from(e.target.files).forEach(file => {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      img.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
    let $div = $('<div class="col-md-2" />').append(img);
    $(e.target).closest('.row').append($div);
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 18rem;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="imagem550x750" role="tabpanel">
  <div class="row" id="imgs550x750">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <label class="btn btn-file">
            Escolha a imagem             
            <input type="file" class="img_load" multiple="multiple" />
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```